# Is it possible to control the Windows SDK version in Windows Kits?

Tags: c++, windows, sdk, visual-studio-2017

Currently when building my Visual C++ application I link out to the Windows SDK in order to use `winusb.h`. This results in an Additional Include Directories with an include for both a um and shared directory,a s shown here:

[image]

Unfortunately, different developers on the project all have different Windows SDK versions installed on their machines, I assume this is to do with either Windows Updates or different Visual Studio installation dates. This means we currently have a whole host of SDK version numbers included in this list.

My question is: **Is there a way to either control the SDK version installed, or to include a more generic directory pathname?**

Comment: The Windows 10 SDK kits are installed from the Visual Studio Installer - your team should agree which kit they are using and then configure the project(s) options to use just that kit.

Comment: @RichardCritten you're right, I think that actually answers the question. Do you want to post an answer or shall I?

Comment: I was only guessing (at your working practices) - please post an complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Richard Critten in the comments of the question, the Windows 10 SDK options are configurable, and installable through the Visual Studio Installer.

As shown below, there are many different options for SDK installation
[image: VS installation options]

It would be sensible to pick one that works for your development environment & team, and ensure every developer has that option installed for their own Visual Studio environment.